# How do I scroll a listview to a specific position on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

My list contains schedules of buses.
I want to scroll the list until the next schedule according to the local time using the SmoothScroll.
Sometimes the list has 40 items and I do not know in what position is the next schedule.
How to know the position of this item and use SmoothScroll?

If you need, I can give more details.

**EDIT 2:**

I've tried this:

Custom adapter overriding this method:

```
public int nextTimePosition;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    String item = getItem(position);

    return (item.equalsIgnoreCase(nextTime)) ? CHANGE_BACKGROUND : TYPE_ITEM_NORMAL;
}
```

if item equals nextTime, I save the position to get on listView class and set smoothscroll, but with no success

**EDIT 3:**

I solved this with SimonSays help.

Before list.post(), I make a query to bring the next schedule in a variable and use the code below to scroll

The method smoothScrollToPosition stopped when he found the next schedule.
But I want the schedule to be centered in the list, so I made some adjustments.

Follows for future reference:

```
lvUtil.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int visibleChildCount = (lvUtil.getLastVisiblePosition() - lvUtil.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
                int finalIndex = uteis.indexOf(getNext()) + (int) Math.floor((visibleChildCount / 2));
                lvUtil.smoothScrollToPosition(finalIndex);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I mean, like what have you tried?

Comment: I can already figure out the next schedule. But through the adapter, I only have the position if the item is visible on the screen and it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to figure that out somehow. This is how it could look. I guess you will need some different logic though.

```
List<Item> myListData = ...;
for(Item item : myListData){
    if(isNextItem(Item){
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListData.indexOf(item));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i get items from list out of adapter?

Comment: How to you put them in?

Comment: See EDIT 3, your answer helped me

Comment: its not working! I'm using in getView() > Custom adapter